# Algorithm that builds heap

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to implement `build_max_heap` function that creates the heap( as it is written in Cormen's "introduction do algorithms" ). But I am getting strange error and i could not localize it. My program successfully give random numbers to table, show them but after `build_max_heap()` I am getting strange numbers, that are probably because somewhere my program reached something out of the table, but I can not find this error. I will be glad for any help.

For example I get the table:

```
0 13 18 0 22 15 24 19 5 23
```

And my output is:

```
24 7 5844920 5 22 15 18 19 0 23
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>  
const int n = 12; // the length of my table, i will onyl use indexes 1...n-1
struct heap
{
    int *tab;
    int heap_size;
};
void complete_with_random(heap &heap2)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 1; i <= heap2.heap_size; i++)
    {
        heap2.tab[i] = rand() % 25;
    }
    heap2.tab[0] = 0;
}
void show(heap &heap2)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < heap2.heap_size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << heap2.tab[i] << " ";
    }
}
int parent(int i)
{
    return i / 2;
}
int left(int i)
{
    return 2 * i;
}
int right(int i)
{
    return 2 * i + 1;
}
void max_heapify(heap &heap2, int i)
{
    if (i >= heap2.heap_size || i == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    int l = left(i);
    int r = right(i);
    int largest;
    if (l <= heap2.heap_size || heap2.tab[l] > heap2.tab[i])
    {
        largest = l;
    }
    else
    {
        largest = i;
    }
    if (r <= heap2.heap_size || heap2.tab[r] > heap2.tab[i])
    {
        largest = r;
    }
    if (largest != i)
    {
        std::swap(heap2.tab[i], heap2.tab[largest]);
        max_heapify(heap2, largest);
    }
}
void build_max_heap(heap &heap2)
{
    for (int i = heap2.heap_size / 2; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        max_heapify(heap2, i);
    }
}
int main()
{
    heap heap1;
    heap1.tab = new int[n];
    heap1.heap_size = n - 1;
    complete_with_random(heap1);
    show(heap1);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    build_max_heap(heap1);
    show(heap1);
}
```

Comment: What kind of heap? Binomial, Binary (as array or as reference structure), Fibonacci?

Comment: @G.Bach Sorry for not including this information. It is Binary Max Heap (reference structure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the table is accessed with out-of-bounds indexes.

```
if (l <= heap2.heap_size || heap2.tab[l] > heap2.tab[i])
                         ^^
```

I think you meant `&&` in this condition.

The same for the next branch with `r`.

Comment: Thank you very much, such a stupid mistake. Algorithm still is not working, but I believe there is a logical mistake somewhere I should find. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. You might want to double-check how you calculate the `largest` index. Do you always get the largest of three values there?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're still having problems, below is my own implementation that you might use for reference. It was also based on Cormen et al. book, so it's using more or less the same terminology. It may have arbitrary types for the actual container, the comparison and the swap functions. It provides a public queue-like interface, including key incrementing.

Because it's part of a larger software collection, it's using a few entities that are not defined here, but I hope the algorithms are still clear. `CHECK` is only an assertion mechanism, you can ignore it. You may also ignore the `swap` member and just use `std::swap`.

Some parts of the code are using 1-based offsets, others 0-based, and conversion is necessary. The comments above each method indicate this.

```
template <
    typename T,
    typename ARRAY = array <T>,
    typename COMP = fun::lt,
    typename SWAP = fun::swap
>
class binary_heap_base
{
protected:

    ARRAY a;
    size_t heap_size;

    SWAP swap_def;
    SWAP* swap;

    // 1-based
    size_t parent(const size_t n) { return n / 2; }
    size_t left  (const size_t n) { return n * 2; }
    size_t right (const size_t n) { return n * 2 + 1; }

    // 1-based
    void heapify(const size_t n = 1)
    {
        T& x = a[n - 1];
        size_t l = left(n);
        size_t r = right(n);
        size_t select =
            (l <= heap_size && COMP()(x, a[l - 1])) ?
            l : n;
        if (r <= heap_size && COMP()(a[select - 1], a[r - 1]))
            select = r;
        if (select != n)
        {
            (*swap)(x, a[select - 1]);
            heapify(select);
        }
    }

    // 1-based
    void build()
    {
        heap_size = a.length();
        for (size_t n = heap_size / 2; n > 0; n--)
            heapify(n);
    }

    // 1-based
    size_t advance(const size_t k)
    {
        size_t n = k;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            size_t pn = parent(n);
            T& p = a[pn - 1];
            T& x = a[n - 1];
            if (!COMP()(p, x)) break;
            (*swap)(p, x);
            n = pn;
        }
        return n;
    }

public:

    binary_heap_base() { init(); set_swap(); }
    binary_heap_base(SWAP& s) { init(); set_swap(s); }

    binary_heap_base(const ARRAY& a) { init(a); set_swap(); }
    binary_heap_base(const ARRAY& a, SWAP& s) { init(a); set_swap(s); }

    void init() { a.init(); build(); }
    void init(const ARRAY& a) { this->a = a; build(); }

    void set_swap() { swap = &swap_def; }
    void set_swap(SWAP& s) { swap = &s; }

    bool empty() { return heap_size == 0; }

    size_t size() { return heap_size; }

    size_t length() { return heap_size; }

    void reserve(const size_t len) { a.reserve(len); }

    const T& top()
    {
        CHECK (heap_size != 0, eshape());
        return a[0];
    }

    T pop()
    {
        CHECK (heap_size != 0, eshape());
        T x = a[0];
        (*swap)(a[0], a[heap_size - 1]);
        heap_size--;
        heapify();
        return x;
    }

    // 0-based
    size_t up(size_t n, const T& x)
    {
        CHECK (n < heap_size, erange());
        CHECK (!COMP()(x, a[n]), ecomp());
        a[n] = x;
        return advance(n + 1) - 1;
    }

    // 0-based
    size_t push(const T& x)
    {
        if (heap_size == a.length())
            a.push_back(x);
        else
            a[heap_size] = x;
        return advance(++heap_size) - 1;
    }

};
```